# Displaying Full Storage Capacity after removing Wndows 10 after a dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I'm not able to access the available storage list. It only shows a partial section of the memory leaving out the former memory which had Windows 10 installed in it. I'm sending a screenshot just for clarification.
MY hard-disk contains 500GiB but it says only 135GiB left
Kindly help pls.

the image shows the partitions and the notification about only showing 135GiB leaving out the rest of the memory

[image: the image shows the partitions and the notification about only showing 135GiB leaving out the rest of the memory]

Comment: system root partition.. while installing ubuntu u have allotted 157GB it seems for root partition.. out of 157GB 135 is available.. means the values are from the root partition allotment at the time of installation..

Comment: It looks to me like all of it is there. If you want to get rid of the Windows things you need to delete the NTFS partitions and then expand your linux partition to fill the space. This will need to be done with a USB install or Live DVD.  I recommend gparted.